# sharepoint list item click event and value change

Tags: sharepoint

So my goal is to allow the user to click the item on the list and it automatically changes a value on the item. Mostly I want a easy to allow the user to mark the item as being read. This list will be updated every week, so it will allow the user to know what is new easier. I have already set up the views so the users can only see their own data on the personal view.

I have looked online and I'm not having great luck. This is what I have so far.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr").click(function(){  //only works before ajax runs
    setTimeout( function() {
    //alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current("https://...");
    var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Ticket');
    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(items[0].id);
    this.oListItem.set_item('read','yes');
    this.oListItem.update(); 
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }, 200);  //had to be put in place to give time for the list to be selected
}); 
});
```

These are the issues I have.

1. the first time I click a item it tells be SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems is null. However if I click the same item it will give me the ID number. Then if I click it a third time it will tell me its null again.
2. It does not change the vaule, but it does give me the right ID number after I click it two times.

EDIT,

see comments below

Comment: OK i got the first issue fixed with making a delay to give time for it to select the item. 
Now about issue 2, when i was playing around with it more im getting a error 
"Uncaught TypeError: items[0].set_item is not a function", i have updated my script above with the delay. Im sure im not calling something right for it to say set_item isnt a function. Any help will be great

Comment: So I got most of it working but now I have a issue with the .click event and Ajax. Do you another way to do a click event that will work with Ajax. or another way to refresh the list after the change. I looked and it seems you need to use the .on, but I cant seem to get it working

Answer (score 0):

Using this code:

```
$("table.ms-listviewtable").on("mouseup", "tr.ms-itmhover", function() {
        //your code
});
```